# removing Images while adding Class attribute to them

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have an XSLT file and an XML file .In the XML file I have Image tag that has Class attribute.when I want to do somthing with these Image from XSL file .the images removed from them i.e:

```
<head>
    <title>ERKLAERUNG</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Erklärung</h1>
    <hr/>
    <p>
      Ich kenne einen Herrn
      <span class="vcard">
        <span class="fn">Henry Riedel</span>

        **<img class="pic"   src="hk.png" />**

        (<i class="nick">hrick</i>) , der in einer
        <span class="org">Hauschuhfirma</span> arbeitet. Seine
        Telefonnummer (
        <span class="tel">
          <i class="type">home</i>) ist:
          <span class="value">+4.444.444.4442</span>
        </span>
      </span>
....
```

when I added these block of code to XSLT file my images with class 'pic' removed:

```
...
<xsl:template match="*[@class='pic']">
    <u>
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
          <xsl:text>show_hcard('</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
          <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </a>
    </u>
  </xsl:template>
...
```

but if I for example change the class name in my XSLT file to i.e 'mmmm' that works good and show me the images
Would you please help me?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You are catching the image element but then not doing anything with it so it is not output. Try something like this. You need to output the existing element and its content when you add your attribute.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" media-type="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[@class='pic']">

        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                <xsl:text>show_hcard('</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="../parent::node()//span[@class='fn']"/>
                <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you jayson for your answer.Would you please explain me ,What makes `<xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">`  this line of code

Comment: local-name gets the name of the element without the namespace prefix (if there is any). In this case local-name(.) with the "." is saying get the name of the current element which is "img" due to your match for the elements with class='pic' finding an "img" element

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this is with the Identity Transform and an appropriate override. Note that the override template copies the existing element's existing attributes and child nodes unmodified; all it does is add one new attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[@class='pic']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                <xsl:text>show_hcard('</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="../span[@class='fn']"/>
                <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Relevant output:

```
<img class="pic" src="hk.png" onclick="show_hcard('Henry Riedel')">
```

The first template copies most elements through unchanged. The second template handles only those elements that have a class attribute whose value is `pic`.

Full input:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>ERKLAERUNG</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Erklärung</h1>
    <hr/>
    <p>
      Ich kenne einen Herrn
      <span class="vcard">
        <span class="fn">Henry Riedel</span>

        **<img class="pic"   src="hk.png" />**

        (<i class="nick">hrick</i>) , der in einer
        <span class="org">Hauschuhfirma</span> arbeitet. Seine
        Telefonnummer (
        <span class="tel">
          <i class="type">home</i>) ist:
          <span class="value">+4.444.444.4442</span>
        </span>
      </span>
      </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Full output:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>ERKLAERUNG</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>ErklÃ¤rung</h1>
      <hr>
      <p>
         Ich kenne einen Herrn
         <span class="vcard"><span class="fn">Henry Riedel</span>

            **<img class="pic" src="hk.png" onclick="show_hcard('Henry Riedel')">**

            (<i class="nick">hrick</i>) , der in einer
            <span class="org">Hauschuhfirma</span> arbeitet. Seine
            Telefonnummer (
            <span class="tel"><i class="type">home</i>) ist:
               <span class="value">+4.444.444.4442</span></span></span></p>
   </body>
</html>
```